# Pass Base64 with POST Request

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript and I get a image file and encode it to base 64 like this

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID



function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
             el("img").src = e.target.result;
             el("base").innerHTML = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

el("asd").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

Where the encoded text is this and looks like this

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTE.........
```

And now I want to send this data with a post which I know how to do, but when I read the data I sent on the other side I just see `data:image/jpeg`, where does the Base64 encoded start and how can I just pass that as a string?

I make the post like this

```
var base64data;
//base64data is declared in the function readImage and I log it in this one and it has data
function callHttpReq () {

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/admin/website_sql/save_info.py";
var params = "website_photo=" + base64data;
http.open("POST", url, true);
console.log(base64data);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the technology you're using in server side

Comment: please show us how you send it

Comment: @Nipuna I am sending it to a python script and getting the data with `form = cgi.FieldStorage()`

Comment: @яша see above I added how I send it

Comment: are   console.log(http.responseText); and console.log(base64data); fine ?